# remove all numbers from textbox C#

Tags: c#

I'm new here. I just want to know how to remove all numbers from a textbox when a button is clicked. For example, if textbox has text hello1, when I click the button it should be hello.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var output = Regex.Replace(textbox.Text, @"[\d-]","");
```

Comment: Hi sir. This is working perfectly. Can you please explain to me some of the code? Thank you.

Comment: The \d identifier simply matches any digit character.if your textbox have any digit number , it's replaced as empty!

Comment: That dash character may cause unwanted consequences. For example `"12 pseudo-codes"` -> `"pseudocodes"`. If the OP is only in interested in removing digits, I think `\d` would suffice.

Comment: @user2442470 if this answer is helpful, then you can accept this answer by clicking tickmark besides this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 textBox1.Text = new string(textBox1.Text.Where(t => t <= '0' || t >= '9').ToArray());
```

This will also do